# How to specify component values in LT Spice PV cell model to match real-world panel Short Circuit & Open Circuit spec?

Tags: ltspice, solar-cell

Images below are from the LT Spice solar cell model I've set up as an approximate representation of the solar panel I'm using for testing.

I'm not sure if I'm setting component values correctly to replicate the maximum Short Circuit and Open Circuit values of this panel.

This video [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2C28OXu4xA) says the Short Circuit value is 'very close' to the value of the Current Source and this video [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZ-3HDjwPWw) says it's 'most strongly' the Diode Saturation Current.

For the first sim [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJP8z.png) I set the Current Source to the panels quoted maximum current of 0.5A and then tweaked the Diode Saturation Current right down until I had approximately the right Wattage at Maximum Power Point and then adjusted the DC sweep Voltage range until I had an I-V curve that started and ended at approximately 0 Watts.

For the second sim [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdq6b.png) I set the Diode Saturation Current to give an Open Circuit Voltage of approx. 12V and tweaked the DC sweep Voltage from there.

For a first proof of concept that I can use to start simulating a real-world panel - is this a correct approach?

My reference panel is a small, cheap thing, there's no data sheet but it's advertised as:

Max Power: 4.2W;
Working Voltage: 12V;
Max Current: 0.35A;
Short Circuit Current: 0.5A;
Size: 20 x 12CM;

[image: Schematic]

[image: Output 1]

[image: Output 2]

[3.1 PV panel Spice model and simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2C28OXu4xA)

[Solar Cell Modelling using LTSpice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZ-3HDjwPWw)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the 2nd video.  It says the diode saturation current mostly affects the **open circuit voltage**, not the short circuit current.  Therefore, both videos are correct.

Comment: As for the modeling, the listed specs have terms like "working voltage" and "max current" which I don't know what they're supposed to mean.  It's possible that "max current" might mean the max it can output before it starts dropping below the "working voltage" of 12V.  That could also be the max power point, since the math works out: 12V / 0.35A = 4.2W. I think your first modeling approach seems to line up with this reasoning better. HOWEVER, I personally would find a nice sunny day outside and bring your equipment out there to do some of your own measurements and not rely on the vague specs.

Comment: @SteKulov You're right - the narrator in the 2nd video mentions short circuit current at that part - but they are referring to open circuit voltage. Thanks for pointing that out.